# Convert Column Timestamp to Date Time

Tags: python, pandas

I have  a dataframe that has a column with a TimeStamp. The data in this column is float64

```
timestamp
1582574539
1582574454
1582573814
1582573499
1582573234
```

I want to convert this column to DateTime or add a new column with the readable DateTime

```
DateTime
2/24/20 14:52
2/24/20 14:50
2/24/20 14:46
```

I tried the following code -

```
df1['DateTime'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(df1.timestamp)
```

And got the following errors -

```
TypeError("cannot convert the series to " "{0}".format(str(converter)))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='s')` ..?

Comment: One way to avoid this would be ```from datetime import datetime; df['times'] = [datetime.fromtimestamp(t) for t in df['timestamp']]```